# apply arcos to out of domain $[-1, 1]$ values, such that -1.02

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, angle

I do apologise if the problem sounds a bit confusing, it's not a complicated question, I will make it short as possible.

I am trying to archive an ellipse parameterisation, with a reference to [SVG implementation notes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html) I met a problem using arc cos

According to the equation of [compute angle between two vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMAld.png), I have two sets of vectors, which I would like to work out the angle between.

Perhaps it's due to precision loss, I had to solve a weird bug, it turns out that, sometimes, I need to work out the arc sin of for example, -1.0002, which breaks my function and return a value of NaN. I have very limited knowledge about arc sin, quickly I used demos tools, [y = arccosx](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dsatqtrgjz)
and it turns out arc cos has a domain [-1, 1].

Now I think I only have two ways to go:

1. for $f(x) = arcos(x)$, if x is out of range, then assign x to the limit value, either 1 or -1;
2. do a few Math.PI*1/2 calculation, convert x into the domain of [-1, 1], work out the arc cos.

Could someone please suggest one way to go, if you can provide me some calculations of work out

- f(x) = arc cos(x), x ∉ [-1, 1]

I will be so grateful for your help.

Comment: See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8489792/428857) and [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8490249/428857).

Comment: $\arccos(x)$ can be defined for $x$ out of range *but* it gives nonreal values. I don't know what Math.PI*1/2 calculations are, but I'd recommend assigning $x$ to the limit value.